# Active Record: Problem with translation template and body error messages in .yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, internationalization

guys! I've successfully done translation for errors messages like this:

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    messages:
      blank: "не может быть пустым"
      invalid: "имеет неверное значение"
      confirmation: "не совпадает с подтверждением"
      ...
```

Also I've translated template and body blocks for erros messages in the same way:

```
template:
  header:
    one: "%{model}: сохранение не удалось из-за %{count} ошибки"
    other: "%{model}: сохранение не удалось из-за %{count} ошибки"
  body: "Проблемы возникли со следующими полями:"
```

But in this case, I'm stil get an original Active Record error message: "1 error prohibited this user from being saved:".

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3.0.5 with Active Record 3.0.5 .

I hope you could help me.

Comment: What validation is on your `ActiveRecord` model?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`russian` gem](https://github.com/yaroslav/russian)?

This gem provide advanced support for some russian specific things like: pluralization, dates and so on.

And, please, can you try this localization:

```
ru:
  # Используется в хелпере error_messages_for
  activerecord:
    errors:
      template:
        # Заголовок сообщения об ошибке
        header:
          one:   "%{model}: сохранение не удалось из-за %{count} ошибки"
          few:   "%{model}: сохранение не удалось из-за %{count} ошибок"
          many:  "%{model}: сохранение не удалось из-за %{count} ошибок"
          other: "%{model}: сохранение не удалось из-за %{count} ошибки"

        # Первый параграф сообщения об ошибке. Можно использовать макрос %{count}
        #
        #
        # The variable :count is also available
        body: "Проблемы возникли со следующими полями:"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks like I'm already used exactly the same translation with few changes, but I've no touched a part with template and body. After your answer, I've used russian gem, but nothing changes.

Comment: if code was scaffolded, can you look at app/views/users/_form.html.erb? In my case this string is hardoced right there, so I18n cann't translate it.

Comment: You can watch example application here: https://github.com/Imomoi/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/5483187/test_app.

It overrides default heading in users/_form.html.erb to translated ones.

But be careful: to bring gem `russian` to work you need current master version from git (see at Gemfile)

Comment: Thank you, Viacheslav. You was right. I'm using Devise gem for authorization, and as I know now it has a stub devise_error_messages! that have no i18n support and you have to override this method in your own devise_helper if you need a i18n or you want to add another customization.